# 502 / 503 / 404 HTTP error : GKE ingress-nginx serving traffic to the wrong services, from other namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this kind of routing in each namespace :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    janitor/expires: ${EXPIRY_DATE}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" # Set to true once SSL is set up.
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: api.${KUBE_DEPLOY_HOST}
      http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /
          backend:
            service:
              name: api-js
              port:
                number: 111
```

Served by ingress-nginx (!= nginx-ingress) 1.2.1 (same issue with 1.5.1) with Kube 1.22 (or 1.23), one deployment in the ingress-nginx namespace, two replicas in the deployment.

When I check my logs I see that sometimes, I think especially when I deploy new ingress rules in new namespaces (during and after the ingress-nginx reload event) I get 502 / 503 / 404 HTTP error responses from the ingress-nginx controller.

When I look into the detailed log, I see :

```
IP - - [time] "GET API_ROUTE HTTP/1.1" 503 592 "master.frontend.url" UA 449 0.000 [development-branch-api] [] - - - - ID
```

Which makes me think the request goes wrong because the master frontend is being served a development API response by the ingress-nginx controller, sometimes when the new api service is not even ready.

When I check the ingress from GKE's view it looks like it is serving 3 pods, corresponding to 3 namespaces that should not overlap / mix requests, instead of the one api pod in the namespace corresponding to the ingress :

[image]

So the error is seen here, all the ingresses for each 3 namespsace serve 3 pods instead of one pod, which means it is all mixed up, right.

I am sure there is one pod per deployment in my namespaces :

[image]

So if I understand correctly, it seems that the situation is ingress A, ingress B and ingress C, all three of them, serve api A AND api B AND api C instead of serving just the one api pod from their namespace (A, B, C).

But what I don't know is how is it possible that the ingress matches pods from other namespaces, when I am not using externalname, it is the opposite of what an ingress does by default.

I believe the issue is at the ingress level and not at the service level, as when I look into each service, I see that it just serve the one pod corresponding to its namespace and not 3.

The controller is the default ingress-nginx installation edited to use 2 replicas instead of one.

Example service and deployment (issue happens for all of them) :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-js
  labels:
    component: api-js
    role: api-js
  annotations:
    janitor/expires: ${EXPIRY_DATE}
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    role: perfmaker-api-js
  ports:
    - name: httpapi
      port: 111
      targetPort: 111
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-js
  annotations:
    janitor/expires: ${EXPIRY_DATE}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-js
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: "false"
      labels:
        app: api-js
        role: api-js
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api-js
          image: registry/api
```

When I change the api name / selectors on one branch, it "untangles" the situation and each branch / namespace's ingress only serves the pod it should serve.

But the errors happen during and after 'reload' event on the ingress-controller, not all the time, an event which is fired when ingress resources are added / removed / updated. In my case it is when there is a new branch in the CI/CD which makes a new namespace and deployment + ingress, or when a finished pipeline triggers a namespace deletion.

Comment: Is your goal to have a separate Ingress per namespace?  It's a bit hard to debug without seeing all of the deployments, services and Ingresses.  With the nginx ingress controller, ingress resources from multiple namespaces are all served by the same nginx server instances.

Comment: @GariSingh I have one ingress-nginx controller with 2 replicas, and one ingress per namespace, corresponding to one branch. It it odd ? I expect that an ingress in a namespace will not serve requests to pods from another namespace but it seems to happen during ingress-nginx RELOAD event, when adding or removing ingress from another namespace.

Comment: @GariSingh The ingress is always the same version but one per namespace : simple selection by service name as shown, and the services are really as simple as the api-js I've shown

Comment: nginx ingress actually serves ingress resources from multiple domains from the same nginx instances.

Comment: @GariSingh I think I may be missing something. I use https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx and I have 2 nginx instances running (one ingress-nginx controller with 2 replicas, in the ingress-nginx namespace), and I expect them to serve requests for N namespaces, each namespace having its own ingress object that describes the routing, for exemple api.branchA.net in namespace A, and api.branchB.net in namespace B. I expect that querying api.branchA.net will always serve a service that is in namespace A, as the ingress object is in namespace A. Does it sounds like standard behaviour / use ?

Comment: In my code samples  the ingress containing   - host: api.${KUBE_DEPLOY_HOST} will be deployed as serving for api.branchA.net and api.branchB.net depending on the namespace it is deployed to

Comment: K8s Ingress resources (kubectl get ingress) can and should be placed in multiple different namespaces. 
K8s Ingress resources are being "listened to" watched and processed by an Ingress Controller (this is not the same as Ingress resource). An Ingress controller is a K8s workload (e.g. a Deployment) that has pods. Nginx ingress, Istio ingress, etc. deploy controller pods to a single central namespace. Those pods get typically exposed as a K8s Service. Network traffic first hits ingress controller pods. Ingress controller pods proxy (redirect) traffic to the app pods in different namespaces.

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov Thanks, that's what I am doing. Still don't know why there is a n intermittent routing mixup during the controller reload events (when ingresses are added or removed)

Comment: You can try to get more on this by extracting logs of corresponding controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas I must admit I just discovered the error does not originate from the kubernetes / ingress-nginx part of the setup but from the testing system, which includes a collision between services at deploy time, because of bad separation in the CI / CD job. Sorry for your time !

So in fact the logs from ingress nginx that stunned me :

```
IP - - [time] "GET API_ROUTE HTTP/1.1" 503 592 "master.frontend.url" UA 449 0.000 [development-branch-api] [] - - - - ID
```

Shows that a service I deploy is overwritten by another environment deployment with different variables, which makes it start to make request to another namespace. The ingress routing is correct.